# Remove '+' after the last output

Tags: c++, string

I have a C++ code that calculates change.

It takes input, and returns output by how change will be received.

I need to remove the + sign after last change output.

Is there a way to do this?

My code:

```
if (n500 > 0) {
        cout << n500 << " x 500 + ";
    }
    if (n200 > 0) {
        cout << n200 << " x 200 + ";
    }
    if (n100 > 0) {
        cout << n100 << " x 100 + ";
    }
    if (n50 > 0) {
        cout << n50 << " x 50 + ";
    }
    if (n20 > 0) {
        cout << n20 << " x 20 + ";
    }
    if (n10 > 0) {
        cout << n10 << " x 10 + ";
    }
    if (n5 > 0) {
        cout << n5 << " x 5 + ";
    }
    if (n2 > 0) {
        cout << n2 << " x 2 + ";
    }
    if (n1 > 0) {
        cout << n1 << " x 1 + ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the other way: put the separator `" + "` when previous display has already be done:

```
const char* sep = "";
if (n500 > 0) {
    std::cout << sep << n500 << " x 500";
    sep = " + ";
}
if (n200 > 0) {
    std::cout << sep << n200 << " x 200";
    sep = " + ";
}
if (n100 > 0) {
    std::cout << sep << n100 << " x 100 + ";
    sep = " + ";
}
if (n50 > 0) {
    std::cout << sep << n50 << " x 50 + ";
    sep = " + ";
}
if (n20 > 0) {
    std::cout << sep << n20 << " x 20 + ";
    sep = " + ";
}
if (n10 > 0) {
    std::cout << sep << n10 << " x 10 + ";
    sep = " + ";
}
if (n5 > 0) {
    std::cout << sep << n5 << " x 5 + ";
    sep = " + ";
}
if (n2 > 0) {
    std::cout << sep << n2 << " x 2 + ";
    sep = " + ";
}
if (n1 > 0) {
    std::cout << sep << n1 << " x 1 + ";
    sep = " + ";
}
```

BTW, you might probably use loop instead:

```
const int ns[9] = {
    n500, n200, n100,
    n50, n20, n10,
    n5, n2, n1
};
const char* texts[9] = {
    " x 500", " x 200", " x 100",
    " x 50", " x 20", " x 10",
    " x 5", " x 2", " x 1"
};

const char* sep = "";
for (int i = 0; i != 9; ++i) {
    if (ns[i] > 0) {
       std::cout << sep << ns[i] << texts[i];
       sep = " + ";
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an identifier "n500" is undefiend on these lines

` const int ns[9] = {
    n500, n200, n100,
    n50, n20, n10,
    n5, n2, n1
}

Comment: You don't provide MCVE... `n500` is YOUR variable (that we assume is defined (as `int` for my part)).

Answer (score -1):

Set a string with all your update, remove the last char then output it with cout.

Look at stringstream